# How to set multiple domain on same ip and differrent port

Tags: domain, website

i have set up a web site on linux server. I want to know that is there any way to set multiple domain on same IP using different PORT? so that I can manage multiple sites on same server(i.e same IP).

Comment: Do you really need different ports? Because it does not make sense to put up  a website per port ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make Apache2 (if you are using Apache2) listen on multiple ports and use vhosts and redirects to put up a site per port.

However, you can also easily manage many websites on one port number and also use vhosts to redirect to these websites.

An example of a vhost can be:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/yoursite
    ServerName www.somesite.com
</VirtualHost>
```